# WPF ListView not showing contents of Observable Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listview

I have a listview in a WPF application which is supposed to display the contents of an observable collection. I had it displaying in an older build, but in trying to make the listview update more often I changed the XAML quite a lot and after putting it back it now doesn't display anything, ever.

Here is the XAML:

```
<TabItem GotFocus="TabSelect">
    <TabItem.Header>
        <TextBlock FontSize="12pt">error log</TextBlock>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <Grid><ListView Name="JfifoList" ItemsSource="{Binding JFifoErrorCollection}" Background="Transparent">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time}" Header="time" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FEStatus}" Header="fe status" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding BEStatus}" Header="be status" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Trigger}" Header="trigger" Width="100" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView></Grid>
</TabItem>
```

I do set up the list's DataContext as "this" window:

```
JfifoList.DataContext = this;
```

When debugging I can see that the collection is populated, so there is data to display... Though also when debugging, I repeatedly see an error that says "A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll" in the debug output.

EDIT: I've looked around some more and found that UI elements must be updated in the UI thread... for some reason (I haven't created any in the code) there are numerous threads running in my program, and they all seem to be updating my ObservableCollection... Don't know whether this might be the problem...

Comment: 1. Do you see any Binding errors as in Binding failing for your `ItemsSource="{Binding JFifoErrorCollection}"` ? 

2. Replace your `ListView` with a `ListBox` and display some member of `JFifoErrorCollection` by setting its `DiaplayMemberPath`. If the listbox displays the data then some issue is with your ListView configuration.

3. Even if you observable collection is populated in another thread, did you raise `NotifyPropertyChanged("JFifoErrorCollection")` in that thread of the viewmodel module?

Comment: Listbox shows nothing too... Doesn't the Observable Collection raise that event itself?

Comment: Actually observable collection is not thread safe sadly. :(

Comment: I don't want multiple threads anyway... They just seem to be there without me asking for them. How can I just run on one thread?

Comment: They're all nameless threads apart from the main thread...

Comment: I'm so confused... if collections aren't threadsafe.. why would the compiler automatically make my program multithreaded without my say so?

Comment: What exactly is the DataContext?

Comment: Read the [data binding overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)...

Comment: In which way does the collection get populated?
Is the collection re-instantiated sometime while the application is running?

Comment: The collection is populated using its .Add() function... Is that wrong?

Comment: H.B. I read the databinding overview but it still didn't help since I am already doing everything I think I should be.

Comment: I changed some stuff according to the overview that H.B. linked to, seems to work now... but it is very slow to update. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifications on the content of lists which are binded to a view, have to be done in a UI thread.
To catch your App UI thread, you can use something like this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => JfifoList = whateverData));
```